# Pthread policy in high contention applications

Tags: pthreads, locking, contention

Anybody knows about how pthread behaves in high contention and low contention situations? As far as I know, there is a unix-base policy (SCHED_OTHER) for mutex handling which optimizes the execution time in terms of contention. I want to know when pthread changes its policy from SCHED_FIFO to SCHED_RR and conversely. How does pthread detect the contention (threshold of changing the policy)?

Comment: You may need to clarify the question. But this could help, see the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908711/linux-pthread-mutex-and-kernel-scheduler

Comment: @ErikAlapää  I would appreciate it if you can give me your gmail address in order ask you some questions about pthread. Thank you in advance.